# bdib() function in xbbg - python

Tags: python, bloomberg

I was trying to collect intraday data from bloomberg and need to set the time interval to 10s  (collect data from the previous day every 10s).

I have tried bdib() in xbbg package, code like this: (Reference: [xbbg document](https://xbbg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/))

```
from xbbg import blp

blp.bdib(ticker='tickername', dt='2021-02-22')
```

and get an error message which is: **Cannot find exchange info for tickername**

I have tried different tickers and got the same error message, and the code is written almost the same as the document. According to this situation, I was wondering if there is any solution to this? And how can I set time interval to 10s using bdib()

Great thanks in advance!

Comment: This answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67336751/xbbg-works-for-historical-but-not-intraday-data-with-regards-to-government-bon/67389113#67389113

You can use the `interval=1` parameter. I am not sure you can have less than 1 minute intervals.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried that method and what I got is a blank return in Jupyter. 
I tried the same request as yours and return "__". 
`blp.bdib(ticker='US912810SM18 Corp', dt='2021-04-16', ref='IndexUS', interval=1).tail()`
Would you happen to know why this happened? Or should I use the start_datetime and end_datetime instead?

Comment: `bdib` will only give you one day at a time.

Comment: Great! Thanks for that, sorry for the stupid question. One last question, I tried several tickers and dts, but there is still nothing return. May I ask why?

Comment: Bloomberg only stores the past 6 months of data, so your date of 16-Apr-21 is too far in the past. `blp.bdib(ticker='US912810SM18 Corp', dt='2022-04-18', ref='IndexUS', interval=30).tail()` returns data.

Comment: Great thanks! Guess I can get my point here